# Table old vs new value on merge?

Tags: oracle

Say I have a table with two columns, `new`, `old`.

Whenever a row is inserte for the first time, `new` will be set and `old` should default to `null`.

Whenever a row is updated, the `new` should become the new value, and `old` should become the replaced value of `new`.

How to do this using Oracle?

Comment: see if this artivcle helps you https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/cfgaudit.htm#i1007238

Answer (score 0):

Like this, I presume.

```
SQL> create table test (id number, old number, new number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (id, new) values (1, 100);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID        OLD        NEW
---------- ---------- ----------
         1                   100

SQL> update test set old = new,
  2                  new = 200
  3    where id = 1;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID        OLD        NEW
---------- ---------- ----------
         1        100        200

SQL>
```